# Unable to register a qml type when working with vlc-qt

Tags: qml

I know this is an old post, but I am trying to do what you did here but I am getting the below error. May you please help, I am new to VLC-Qt thing.

Thank you.

```
    C:/Qt/5.15.0/mingw81_32/include/QtCore/qmetatype.h:1590: undefined reference to `VlcQmlPlayer::staticMetaObject'
debug/main.o: In function `ZN18QMetaTypeIdQObjectIP12VlcQmlPlayerLi8EE14qt_metatype_idEv':
C:/Qt/5.15.0/mingw81_32/include/QtCore/qmetatype.h:1951: undefined reference to `VlcQmlPlayer::staticMetaObject'
debug/main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN11QQmlPrivate11QQmlElementI12VlcQmlPlayerEE[__ZTVN11QQmlPrivate11QQmlElementI12VlcQmlPlayerEE]+0x8): undefined reference to `VlcQmlPlayer::metaObject() const'
debug/main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN11QQmlPrivate11QQmlElementI12VlcQmlPlayerEE[__ZTVN11QQmlPrivate11QQmlElementI12VlcQmlPlayerEE]+0xc): undefined reference to `VlcQmlPlayer::qt_metacast(char const*)'
debug/main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN11QQmlPrivate11QQmlElementI12VlcQmlPlayerEE[__ZTVN11QQmlPrivate11QQmlElementI12VlcQmlPlayerEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `VlcQmlPlayer::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)'
debug/main.o: In function `ZN11QQmlPrivate11QQmlElementI12VlcQmlPlayerED1Ev':
C:/Qt/5.15.0/mingw81_32/include/QtQml/qqmlprivate.h:144: undefined reference to `VlcQmlPlayer::~VlcQmlPlayer()'
```

Comment: You need to link your application with `VLCQt` libraries. Check one of [examples](https://github.com/vlc-qt/examples/tree/master/simple-player) and start your application from that. You probably miss `FIND_PACKAGE(VLCQt REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)` in your CMake or `LIBS += -L/path/to/libs/vlc-qt/lib -lVLCQtCore -lVLCQtWidgets` if you use `.pro`

Comment: This question seems like it's referring to another question, but there's no link.

Comment: My code is as shown below

Main.cpp

    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<VlcQmlSource>("VlcSource", 1, 1, "VlcSource", QStringLiteral("VlcQmlSource cannot be instantiated directly"));
    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<VlcTrackModel>("VlcTrackModel", 1, 1, "VlcTrackModel", QStringLiteral("VlcTrackModel cannot be instantiated directly"));
    qmlRegisterType<VlcQmlVideoOutput>("VlcVideoOutput", 1, 1, "VlcVideoOutput");
    qmlRegisterType<VlcQmlPlayer>("VlcPlayer", 1, 1, "VlcPlayer");